# I/O redirection in a C program

Tags: redirect, io

I want to implement a simple "cat file1 > file1" command in a C program. I have tried the following, but it does not work...

```
main () {
    pid_t pid;
    FILE *ip, *op;
    char *args[3];
    printf("Name of the executable program\n\t");
    scanf("%s", &name[0]); // I entered cat here
    printf("Name of the input file\n\t");
    scanf("%s", &name[1]); //file1.txt
    printf("Name of the output file\n\t");
    scanf("%s", &name[0]); //file2.txt
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == -1)
        perror("fork() error");
    else if(pid > 0)
        waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
    else if (pid == 0) {
        op = fopen(name[2], "w");
        close(1);
        dup(op);
        execlp(name[0], name[1], NULL);
        }
    return 0;
    }// end of main()
```

I thought the `execlp()` will run `cat file1.txt` and its output will be redirected to `file2.txt`, but it's not and I don't know why. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%s", &name[0]); // I entered cat here
printf("Name of the input file\n\t");
scanf("%s", &name[1]); //file1.txt
printf("Name of the output file\n\t");
scanf("%s", &name[0]); //file2.txt
```

Clearly not a C&P of actual code - `name` should be `args`, and the last one should be "2" instead of 0.

Also, dup works on file descriptors, not FILE*, so need to look at open rather than fopen, or whatever method gets the fd from a FILE*

Comment: Ok after modification, what i get during runtime is 
shit: standard output: Bad file descriptor

Comment: updated answer - all based on memory though, fingers crossed I've remembered correctly...

Comment: The function to get a file descriptor from a file stream is `fileno()`.  Don't forget to `close()` or `fclose()` the stream that is `dup()`'d before the `execlp()`.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to [`execlp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) is the name to be looked up; the second and following arguments are the `argv` list, starting with `argv[0]`.

```
int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg0, ... /*, (char *)0 */);
```

For shell I/O redirection, it is easier to open files with `open()` than to use standard I/O (`<stdio.h>` and `FILE *`); you should also close the file you opened after the `dup()`, though it is easier to use `dup2()`.  You need to allocate space to read the strings into; on many systems, the original code would crash because the pointers in `str` don't point anywhere.  You should normally aim to exit with status 0 only if everything worked; otherwise, exit with a non-zero exit status.

This leads to:

```
#include <fcntl.h>      /* open() */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>   /* waitpid() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* execlp(), fork(), dup2() */

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t corpse;
    int   status;
    char  name[3][50];
    printf("Name of the executable program\n\t");
    if (scanf("%49s", name[0]) != 1)
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    printf("Name of the input file\n\t");
    if (scanf("%49s", name[1]) != 1)
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    printf("Name of the output file\n\t");
    if (scanf("%49s", name[2]) != 1)
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("fork() error");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
        corpse = waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
    else
    {
        int fd = open(name[2], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644);
        if (fd < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for writing\n", name[2]);
            return(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        dup2(fd, 1);
        close(fd);
        execlp(name[0], name[0], name[1], NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to exec %s\n", name[0]);
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return(corpse == pid && status == 0 ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to either use fork() a process and reassign it's file descriptors to previously(manually) open()'ed file, or use system() call to make shell handle it for you.